# Can not load XML into Properties Object Java

Tags: java, xml

Hi I have a problem when trying to load an XML file into Properties Object in Java. This is what I am trying to do:

```
public class loadXML() {

private dbConn

public loadXML(Connection currConn) {
     this.dbConn = currConn;
}

public Properties populateProperties() {
     ResultSet rst;
     Statement stmt;
     Connection con;
     Properties prop;

     con = dbConn.getConnection();
     stmt = conn.createStatement();
     rst.executeQuery("SELECT xml_row FROM xml_table");

     if (rst.next()) {
          prop = new Properties();
          /* Old Code */
          System.out.println(((XMLType)rst.getObject("xml_row")).getStringVal()); // * Note 1
          prop.loadFromXML(((XMLType)rst.getObject("xml_row")).getInputStream());
          /* Old Code */

          /* New Code */

          // transform xml loaded from database into byte stream.
          byte[] bytes = ((XMLType)rst.getObject("xml_row")).getDOM().toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
          // Load stream into properties object
          prop.loadFromXML(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));

          /* New Code */
     }

     return prop;
}

}
```

Below is the XML extract as it is saved in the database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="key-name">01234</entry>
    <entry key="key-name">123456</entry>
</properties>
```

Note 1 - This is what the System.out.println() is showing on screen:

XML Extract

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone='no'?>
<!DOCTYPE properties>
<!--Copyright 2006 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.-->
<!-- DTD for properties -->
<properties version="1.0">
  <entry key="key-name">01234</entry>
  <entry key="key-name">123456</entry>
</properties>
```

Where I noticed that the version attribute is added to the element Properties (which however does not really bother me), however the problem is that the link to the DTD is removed (i.e SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd") which is triggering an error when executing the following line of code:

```
prop.loadFromXML(((XMLType)rst.getObject("xml_row")).getInputStream());
```

Below is the error:

java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: : XML-20149: (Error) Element 'properties' used but not declared.

Comment: I managed to find what was the problem with this. Nothing was wrong within the Java code. I am using an Oracle 10g database, xml_row in xml_table was declared as XML type. Oracle 10g automatically tries to validate the XML data stored in the xml_row against the DTD when it is being retrieved from the database. In my case the database server was installed on a machine without access to internet, which triggered the error. What I did was to change the row type to CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the DTD has been added at least partially. The two comment lines are from the original DTD file found at the system URL. But the element and attribute declarations are missing. Maybe the ResultSet::getObject implementation from the database driver is .. say .. not fully tested.